# Why does the Database Repair Tool require a fresh installation?

Tags: repair-tool

I've used the Magento Database Repair Tool a couple of times and I'm always puzzled at why it needs a fresh database installation.

Would it not be more efficient to have a database tool per Magento Version?

Could someone explain why this is necessary if Magento is standard (no other distros), wouldn't all the tables ect be the same from one installation to another?

Comment: Tough crowed for voting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wants a fresh installation because it wants a completely uncontaminated, newly created database for the exact version you are running. It essentially diffs your database schema against the newly installed schema, makes corrections to the table fields, keys and then data cleanup.

A per version would mean that you'd need one for 1.9.0.0, 1.9.0.1, 1.9.1.0, 1.9.1.1, 1.9.2.0, 1.9.2.1 and that doesn't even begin to address 1.8.x.x and earlier, or any of the intermediate versions back in the release archive that are no longer available, but which some website operator got stuck on due to Magento's notorious upgrade whompus causing them to lose courage to go on.

Having a database tool for each version of Magento would lead to an untenable mess.

Even [Magereverse](http://www.magereverse.com/) gave up on tracking all the changes over time...

If you have your original install archive kept somewhere safe (you do have it on file don't you?), you will always be able to run the database tool.

[Official Magento Database Repair Tool Documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/database-repair-tool.html)

Comment: Maybe not "**per version**", it baffles me that there isn't one tool for all that doesn't require an installation to match it against. There doesn't seem to be any reason for this.

Comment: The reason for this is that each version has table and field modifications in its sql updates. The database schema and number of tables potentially changes every time there is a version upgrade or a module install. **That** is the reason. The only thing you have to compare against is an empty database from a fresh install. It's an obvious DBA issue. Magento would have to provide a schema library for each version and then the matching version would then have to be modified for installed modules. You are seeing expedient programming in action.

Answer (score 3):

I've always found this to be by design.  You can put a fresh install on your server of any version, as well you can add all your extensions to this fresh install.

The db repair tool will check not only against core Magento tables, but also tables from your custom extensions.

In this way the db repair tool is very flexible, and can help you with your own environment.

Because of this it was also be too much work to maintain different base versions, since environment vary much more than just core Magento version.

Comment: If it does check against custom extension then this would make sense to me. +1

Comment: Yes. I've done it on several occasions.  It only cares about tables, table structures, indexes , and foreign keys. Doesn't evaluate if it's a core table etc.  It's saved the day for me a couple times.

Comment: _The db repair tool will check not only against core Magento tables, but also tables from your custom extensions._ The really important reason for the freshly created database from your current installation, few customized Magento installations are exactly alike. New module, new schema.

Comment: Yep. That's the point.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty for the information about the tool checking against extensions but couldnt award the answer as it wasnt a complete answer. Thanks! SR

Comment: Thank you.  I've updated my answer to be more complete anyway.  Thank you!  Fun to win the bounty.